# ¿Cómo agrego un valor a un arreglo asociativo en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Tengo un arreglo asociativo en mi script de php al que tengo que añadirle elementos según se cumplan algunas condiciones. Mi arreglo empieza asi:

```
$arreglo = ["id" => $_POST["id"]];
```

Cuando se cumpla cierta condición, tengo que agregar más elementos para que el arreglo tenga la información de, por ejemplo, lo que está en `$_POST["nombre"]`, `$_POST["apellido"]`, etc. El objetivo es usar ese arreglo asociativo en un objeto `PDO` para ejectuar una consulta de forma segura. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen dos posibles formas de hacerlo, bastante sencillas.

1. Acceder directamente al arreglo

Igual que se haria con un arreglo no asociativo, podemos escribir:

```
$arreglo["nombre"] = $_POST["nombre"];
$arreglo["apellido"] = $_POST["apellido"];
```

Siendo el resultado (con valores hipotéticos)

```
{["id"] => 4, ["nombre"] => "Juan", ["apellido"] => "Mata"}
```

2. Usar la función `array_merge` de PHP

Se puede crear otro arreglo asociativo con la información que tenemos. Se utiliza la función `array_merge` para "unir" estos dos arreglos y la función devuelve un nuevo arreglo con los elementos de ambos arreglos.

```
$arreglo1 = array("nombre" => $_POST["nombre"], "apellido" => $_POST["apellido"]);
$arreglo_resultante = array_merge($arreglo, $arreglo1);
```

Siendo el contenido de $arreglo_resultante

```
{["id"] => 4, ["nombre"] => "Juan", ["apellido"] => "Mata"}
```

La información e idea principal de esta respuesta se han tomado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960730/add-values-to-an-associative-array-in-php) en el sitio en inglés.