# ¿Cómo puedo agregar subarreglos sobre un índice específico? php

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Un arreglo

```
$arreglo = array(
'form' => array(
    'descripcion' => array(
        'titulo' => 'test',
        'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
    ),
    'frutas' => array(
        array(
            'nombre' => 'Manzana',
            'color' => 'Roja',
            'Sabor' => 'Dulce',
            ),
        array(
            'nombre' => 'Pera',
            'color' => 'Verde',
            'Sabor' => 'Dulce',
            ),
        ),
    'submit' => array(
        'titulo' => 'Guardar',
    ),
),
);
print_r($arreglo);
```

Después lo que necesito es:
Agregar subarreglos sobre el índice frutas, lo mas cercano que e logrado es:

```
array_push($arreglo, array('frutas' => array(
        array(
            'nombre' => 'Fresa',
            'color' => 'Rojo',
            'Sabor' => 'Dulce',
            ),
        ),));
```

pero lo anterior genera un indice nuevo y yo necesito el mismo.
¿Cómo puedo agregar subarreglos sobre el índice frutas?

Comment: Talvez esta pregunta: [¿Como agrego un valor a un arreglo asociativo en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83755/c%c3%b3mo-agrego-un-valor-a-un-arreglo-asociativo-en-php) te pueda ayudar, ya que tu pregunta es un posible duplicado de esta ultima.

Comment: No exactamente Kenny aunque es verdad que une a dos arreglos mira lo que dice php: Si los arrays de entrada tienen las mismas claves de tipo string, el último valor para esa clave sobrescribirá al anterior. Sin embargo, los arrays que contengan claves numéricas, el último valor no sobrescribirá el valor original, sino que será añadido al final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de realizar un push, podrías realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$arreglo['form']['frutas'][] = array(
    'nombre' => 'Fresa',
    'color' => 'Rojo',
    'Sabor' => 'Dulce',
);
```

Eso agregaría una nueva fruta, dentro de `frutas`

Comment: Muy bien @Cesar Romero, es exactamente lo que necesitaba